# UnityのAndroidからのプッシュ通知クリアについて

Tags: android, unity3d

Unityのプッシュ通知でPrime31を利用しようと考えています。
通知自体は
iOS：NotificationServices.ScheduleLocalNotification()
Android： EtceteraAndroid.scheduleNotification()
にて可能なのですが、
アプリに戻ってきた時に既存のプッシュ通知をキャンセルする方法がAndroidでは動作しません。
iOSでは、NotificationServices.CancelAllLocalNotifications()を使用すれば動作するのですが、
AndroidのEtceteraAndroid.cancelAllNotifications()は動作しないようです。

Androidでプッシュ通知のクリアを行っている方が居ましたら
どのように実行しているか教えていただきたいです。

Answer (score 1):

prime31の公式に記述されていますが、
https://prime31.com/docs#androidEtc

Note: Android notifications have had many bugs over the various Android versions. If you intend to cancel notifications some Android versions will not actually cancel all notifications when you call cancelAllNotifications. It is recommended to use the cancelNotification method with the notificationId returned when you call scheduleNotification.

EtceteraAndroid.cancelAllNotifications()が効かない場合があり
個別に登録した通知をEtceteraAndroid.cancelNotification()して
消すしか無いようでした。

こちらでも同じ症状に悩まされ、結局
EtceteraAndroid.cancelNotification()と
EtceteraAndroid.cancelAllNotifications()を両方呼ぶことで対処しています。